# TODAY() Function in Foundry Fusion Sheets

Tags: function, palantir-foundry, fusion

I am pretty new to Fusion Sheets and want to prepare some data.
As it seems, there is no TODAY() function existing as far as I could tell.
So I was thinking of creating a custom function in order to do so. But the documentation is not giving any guidance of which kind of coding language to be used. Or at least I did not find anything.

I would be very thankful if any of you could give a hint on how to get the today date or how to write a custom function.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Eiko, Fusion Sheets are not intended to have feature parity with excel or google sheets. Thus there are many functions that don't exist. You should consider doing data manipulation on transforms or other tools like contour, code workbooks, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved it by adding the function inside contour.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a dataset built on a schedule each day that just returns the current date, e.g.:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from transforms.api import transform_df, Output
from datetime import datetime


@transform_df(Output("/path/to/your/today/dataset"))
def compute(ctx):
    return ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(
        [[datetime.now()]],
        T.StructType([T.StructField("today", T.DateType())])
    )
```

Then you can import this in Fusion by adding it to the index and using the lookup function:

```
=lookup('/path/to/your/today/dataset', 'today')
```